# How to get the value from the frontend form and save value to the blockchain using +web3 1.0.0-beta.37 + reactjs

Tags: solidity, blockchain, react, web3js-v1.x

I am writing my first Dapp and want to save the value of the form to the blockchain. I am Using React and web3 js 1.0.0-beta.37 on the frontend. Also I am new to react.

Following is my App.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import FormSubmitContract from './contracts/FormSubmit.json';
import TruffleContract from 'truffle-contract';
import getWeb3 from './utils/getWeb3.js';
import $ from 'jquery';


class App extends Component {
 state = {
   web3:null,
   email:null,
   password:null,
   address1:null,
   address2:null,
   city:null,
   state:null,
   zip:null

 };

 componentDidMount = async () => {
   try{
     const web3 = await getWeb3();
     //console.log(web3);
     const accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts();
    //console.log(accounts);
    const networkId = await web3.eth.net.getId();
    //console.log(networkId);
    //console.log(FormSubmitContract.networks);
    const deployedAddress = 
    FormSubmitContract.networks[networkId].address;
    //console.log(deployedAddress);
    const ContractInstance = new 
    web3.eth.Contract(FormSubmitContract.abi, deployedAddress);

    this.setState({web3, accounts, contract:ContractInstance})
   }catch(error){
    console.log(error);
  }
}

onSubmit = async (event) => {
event.preventDefault();

const FormSubmit = TruffleContract(FormSubmitContract);
FormSubmit.setProvider(this.state.web3.currentProvider);
this.state.web3.eth.getAccounts((error,accounts) => {
  FormSubmit.deployed().then((instance) => {
    // Forminstance = instance;
 }).then(result => {
   return FormSubmit.setData($("#inputEmail4").val(), 
 $("#inputPassword4").val(), $("#inputAddress1").val(),
    $("#inputAddress2").val(), $("#inputCity").val(), 
     $("#inputState").val(), $("#inputZip").val() ,{from: 
     accounts[0]});     
    }).catch(() => {
   console.log("Error in getting the data is printed");
   })
 })
}
```

setData function in contract

```
function setData(string memory _email, string memory _password, string 
memory _address1,
string memory _address2, string memory _city, string memory _state, 
string memory _zip) public
{
  email = _email;
  password = _password;
  address1 = _address1;
  address2 = _address2;
  city = _city;
  state = _state;
  zip = _zip;
}
```

I want to store the submitted form on the blockchain but My problem is I am not getting data and  "Error in getting the data" is in the console log.

I think there is a problem in setData as I don't know how to pass the data in the parameter.

If you can share any material regarding the form submission or Initial level Dapp then it will be very helpful.

Thanks.

Comment: can you add your contract code, or at least the method setData(...)

Comment: @MajdTL add the setData function. please check

Comment: Try to use await/async the code looks better than with "then".                                                                     
    // Stores data
    await FormSubmit.methods.setData(.....).send({ from: accounts[0] });

    // you need getData method in smart contract
    const response = await FormSubmit.methods.getData().call();

Comment: look at this truffle box it could help you https://truffleframework.com/boxes/react

Comment: anyway you will not get the data, you could get the transaction receipt, to get the data you need another call, you are not using web3 directly so take look at this https://truffleframework.com/docs/truffle/getting-started/interacting-with-your-contracts

Comment: Thanks for helping. Can you show any sample app for getting the data via form and storing then to blockchain. I really appreciate.

Comment: I dont know alot about react, but this react box do exactly the same with a simple smart contract, and it is really good structured and coded https://github.com/truffle-box/react-box , https://truffleframework.com/boxes/react , try to download the box and run it, and then start changing it step by step with tests